# Laravel : how to maintain different sessions of a same page?

Tags: laravel, session, session-variables, session-state, laravel-session

I need to put session on the same page sidebar. when user click on any button session will get for that tab. like

- Search Job
- Customers
- etc

In the sidebar the button or not link with any page. i am creating a dialogue box for each so their is no page for the links that's why i am facing the problem. when user click any of the sidebar button the name should highlight.

**DashboardController**

```
 public function disp()
{
    Session::put('page', 'search-job');
    Session::put('page', 'customer');

    return view('front.disp');
}
```

**layout.blade.php**

```
 @if(Session::get('page')=="search-job")
 <?php $active = "active"; ?>
 @else
 <?php $active = ""; ?>
 @endif

 <li class="nav-item {{$active}}">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
       <span class="title">SEARCH JOBS</span>
    </a>
 </li>


 @if(Session::get('page')=="customer")
 <?php $active = "active"; ?>
 @else
 <?php $active = ""; ?>
 @endif

<li class="nav-item {{$active}}">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
       <span class="title">Customer</span>
    </a>
 </li>
```

How to handle on this sidebar

Thanks!

Comment: you want to have 2 active sidebar at same time?

Comment: @BabakAsadzadeh no i want to active one at a time.

Comment: but here you are putting 2 values for page at same time ```Session::put('page', 'search-job'); Session::put('page', 'customer');``` and the second one overrides then the value of page becomes ```customer```

Comment: @BabakAsadzadeh yes this is the problem, how to manage it??
because there is no other function for dashbaord controller to put separately

Answer (score 0):

as i understand from the comments you want to have different active sessions then you have 2 options like below:

1. put them in different indexes like this:

   ```
   Session::put('page-search-job', true);
   Session::put('page-customer', false);
   ```

   and in view check them like this:

   ```
   <li class="nav-item {{ Session::get('page-search-job') == true ? 'active' : '' }}">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
           <span class="title">SEARCH JOBS</span>
       </a>
   </li>
   ```
2. put it in an array like this:

   ```
   Session::put('page', [
       "search-job"=>true,
       "customer"=>false
   ]);
   ```

   and in view check them like this:

   ```
   <li class="nav-item {{ Session::get('page')['search-job'] == true ? 'active' : '' }}">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
           <span class="title">SEARCH JOBS</span>
       </a>
   </li>
   ```

Comment: when i run it, it shows an error 
"Cannot access offset of type string on string (View:"

Comment: what did you do exactly?